# Pandas datetime day frequency to week frequency

Tags: python, pandas, date, data-conversion

Q1:
I have the following pandas dataframe:

[image]

with a huge number of rows with a daily frequency (the *Data* column).
I would like to convert the dataframe in a week base, meaning that the frequency is not diary but now is weekly. Also with this the Money and the workers are the "week sum".

Q2:
Is it possible to define the starting day (by date) of the week?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first make sure your "Date" column is of type datetime.
Consider this example:

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Money=np.random.rand(len(tidx)) * 1000,
        Workers=np.random.randint(1, 11, len(tidx)),
        Date=tidx
    ))
```

---

When we `resample` we can pass a string that represents the time unit by which we resample.  When using `W` for weeks we can actually pass `W-Mon` through `W-Sun`.  So if you have a date

```
date=pd.to_datetime('2012-03-31')
```

Which was a Saturday, we can produce the correct resample unit string

```
'W-{:%a}'.format(date)

'W-Sat'
```

Then we can resample with it

```
df.resample('W-{:%a}'.format(date), on='Date').sum().reset_index()
```

[image]

The simple answer is to `resample` without it, which produces a different starting point.

```
df.resample('W', on='Date').sum().reset_index()
```

[image]